# Send POST request to apollo server with "operationName" and "variables"

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I follow this doc https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/requests.html#postRequests and try to send a `POST` request to apollo server.

test code:

```js
it('should get author correctly', () => {
    const body = {
      query: `
        query {
          getAuthor($id: Int!) {
            name
          }
        }
      `,
      // operationName: 'query author',
      variables: {
        id: 1
      }
    };
    return rp.post(body).then(res => {
      expect(res.data.getAuthor.name).to.equal('lin');
    });
  });
```

`rp.js`:

```js
const requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { PORT } = require('./config');

const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = `http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`;

function rp(options) {
  function post(body) {
    return requestPromise(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, {
      method: 'POST',
      body,
      json: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    post
  };
}

module.exports = rp;
```

When I run `npm test` command, got an error:

```sh
graphql test suites
Go to http://localhost:3000/graphiql to run queries!
    ✓ t0
    1) should get author correctly


  1 passing (79ms)
  1 failing

  1) graphql test suites
       should get author correctly:
     StatusCodeError: 400 - {"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Expected Name, found $","locations":[{"line":3,"column":21}]}]}
      at new StatusCodeError (node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
      at Request.plumbing.callback (node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
      at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
      at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of your query is not valid. There's actually two things wrong. One, variables are defined at the very top of the operation (next to the `query` or `mutation` keyword). And, two, if you define a variable, you have to use it. So your query should look more like this:

```
query($id: Int!) {
  getAuthor(id: $id) {
    name
  }
}
```